# Grouping the alternating harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I want to show that

$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^r} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{3^r} - \frac{1}{4^r} \right)  + \left( \frac{1}{5^r} - \frac{1}{6^r} \right) + \cdots
$$
is absolutely convergent, where $0 < r \le 1$.

My idea is to use the comparison test and find a convergent series that is greater than or equal to the series above. I am not sure which series to use though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series is
$$\sum \left( \frac{1}{(2k-1)^r}- \frac{1}{(2k)^r}\right)$$

For all $k \geq 1$, you have
$$ \frac{1}{(2k-1)^r}- \frac{1}{(2k)^r} \geq 0$$

So the absolute convergence of your series in the same as its convergence, which can be proved by the general criteria for alternating series.

Comment: I want to show that after "grouping" two terms together, the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: You've ignored the parentheses.

Comment: @Smith Is is better now ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That makes sense.

Comment: It's correct, but you could state it more explicitly. The partial sums form a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums of the convergent alternating series.